# Regex to match unquoted strings but not numbers in CSV

Tags: javascript, regex, json

Trying to write a regex for my text editor (BBEdit) to encode strings that are not already quoted within an almost correctly syntaxed JSON style object so that I can use within a JavaScript context that would otherwise see these text strings as undefined variables.

Thus :

```
[ 0, 0, Header, 1, 17, 480 ],
[ 1, 0, Start_track ],
[ 1, 0, Title_t, "Dance of the knights (Romeo & Juliet)" ],
[ 1, 0, Tempo, 600000 ],
[ 1, 0, Time_signature, 4, 2, 24, 8 ],
[ 1, 0, Key_signature, 1, "major" ]
```

would become:

```
[ 0, 0, "Header", 1, 17, 480 ],
[ 1, 0, "Start_track" ],
[ 1, 0, "Title_t", "Dance of the knights (Romeo & Juliet)" ],
[ 1, 0, "Tempo", 600000 ],
[ 1, 0, "Time_signature", 4, 2, 24, 8 ],
[ 1, 0, "Key_signature", 1, "major" ]
```

Comment: Where did the input string come from?

Comment: It's from a MIDI file, parsed via [midicsv](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/midicsv/) - I'm playing with the HTML5 audioContext and building a JavaScript implementation

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below regex.

```
([\[,]\s*)([A-Za-z_]\S*)(?=,|\s*\])
```

And then replace the match with `$1"$2"`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qG0zK1/1)

**Example:**

```
> var s = '[ 1, 0, Title_t, "Dance of the knights (Romeo & Juliet)" ],';
> s.replace(/([\[,]\s*)([A-Za-z_]\S*)(?=,|\s*\])/g, '$1"$2"')
'[ 1, 0, "Title_t", "Dance of the knights (Romeo & Juliet)" ],'
```

Comment: I hate to be defeated ;-)

Comment: Your regex matches the `, d` in `, "a b c, d, e"`, so it's not correct. A better approach is to identify `(,\s*)[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` (a valid javascript identifier after a comma), but not if it matches `(,\s*)("([^"]|\\.)*"|'([^']|\\.)*')` (a valid quoted ---single or double-- string in javascript) (I don't know all about newer regex syntax to use `(?` operators, but I know this can be written using that syntax)

Comment: I don't think this will match fields containing alphabetical and numeric characters despite these fields being string literals